# Qt using parametre of the signal

Tags: qt, int, qt-signals

I created a signal, which is emitted when the user input something(a number) in a qlineedit field, the signal is emitted with a parametre(the number that the user just type in the field). And i would like to use that parametre as a regular number(in a variable).  Im trying to add that signal parametre to another number, and i had an error "s1 is not declared". Here is my class in the .h file and his implementation in the .cpp file

the.h file

```
class fenetre: public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    fenetre();

public slots:
    void calc();
    void clearinput();

signals:
    void thesecond(int s1);

private:
    QPushButton *button1;
    QPushButton *button2;
    QPushButton *button3;
    QPushButton *button4;
    QPushButton *button5;
    QPushButton *result0;
    QPushButton *clear;
    QLineEdit *input1;
    //QLineEdit *inputsqrt;
    //QLineEdit *input2;
    //QLineEdit *result;
    //QLineEdit *square;
};
```

the.cpp file

```
QObject::connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(calc()));
    //QObject::connect(button2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(calc()));
    //QObject::connect(button3,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(calc()));
    //QObject::connect(button4,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(calc()));
    //QObject::connect(button5,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(calc()));
    //QObject::connect(clear,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(clearinput()));

    //QObject::connect(result0,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(calc()));

    QObject::connect(result0,SIGNAL(thesecond(int)),this,SLOT(calc()));


}





void fenetre::calc()
{
    QString s=input1->text();
    bool ok;
   if(!input1->text().isEmpty())
   {
       int s1=s.toInt(&ok,10);
       emit thesecond(s1);
       input1->clear();
   }

   QObject* obj=sender();
   if(obj==result0)
   {
       int s2=s.toInt(&ok,10);
       int A=s2+thesecond(s1);
        input1->clear();
        QString c=QString::number(A);
        input1->setText(c);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense.

`calc()` doesn't pass a parameter. There is no `s1` for you to use in `calc()`. There is one you declare in the first `if` statement, but since it is declared in the block, it is out of scope after the block. Then you are using the signal as a function with a return type, which is kind of odd, considering the signal itself is declared with a `void` return type. Signals in Qt can return values, but that's extremely rarely used, and it will have to actually return a value for that to work.

`QPushButton` doesn't have a `thesecond(int s1)` signal. The last connection statement fails. You don't even check whether it does.

If we assume that in the last connection you meant to say `this` instead of `result0`, then what you end up with is a button connecting to `calc()` which emits a signal, connected to... `calc()` again!

All in all, your code is conceptually entirely wrong, and you don't seem to know what you are doing. Also, you might want to learn a bit on proper coding conventions, because that code is atrocious.

I suggest you edit the question and carefully explain what you actually want to happen, because the way it is right now, your intent is a mystery. Judging by your other questions, it definitely looks like you are getting ahead of yourself, go back and do more learning before you try to use it. You will have a very bad time with programming if you don't have a clue what you are doing. There is a huge difference between making occasional mistakes and having no idea what you are doing, the former is the scope of this site, the second isn't.